# Using Simple_Form for Searching - Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm attempting to a create a simple form that allows me to run a new search on the existing 'results' page using simple form.

The exact same code works fine when performing the search from another (landing) page. However, when I try to insert it into the results page I'm getting

```
undefined method 'vtype' for #
<Venue::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd6860eb730>
```

`vtype` is both a table column and also the name of the param i'm passing to search on.

The simple_form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :results, html: { class: "form-inline justify-content-center" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.select :vtype, options_for_select([['Happy Hours Anywhere','Anywhere'],['After Work Drinks','After Work Drinks'],['Somewhere to Relax with Friends', 'Relaxing with Friends'], ['A Club Night','Club Night'], ['Somewhere for Date Night','Date Night'], ['A Place to Watch Sports', 'Watching Sports']]),{} ,:class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight"  %>
     starting
    <%= f.select :date, options_for_select(dates_for_search_select.each_with_index.map{|d, i| [d[1],d[0]]}), {}, :class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight" %>
     at
    <%= f.select :time, options_for_select(times_for_search_select.each_with_index.map{|d, i| [d[1],d[0]]}), {}, :class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight" %>
 </h4>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Discover', :class => 'btn btn-block btn-danger btn-embossed top-margin ' %>
    <%end%>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def results

    if params.has_key?(:results)

    #@results = Venue.joins(:offers).where("offers.offertype = '2-4-1'")

    @finddate = (params[:results][:date]).to_date
    @findtime = (params[:results][:time]).to_time
    @resultsdate = DateTime.new(@finddate.year,@finddate.month,@finddate.day,@findtime.hour)
    @results = Venue.joins(:offers).where(["venues.vtype = ? and offers.start >= ?", params[:results][:vtype], @resultsdate])

    else

    @results = Venue.joins(:offers).where(["offers.start = ?", Date.today])

    end

  end
```

What's wrong with this form running on the 'results' page?

Comment: should it be `simple_form_for :@results` ?

Comment: Where is the error raises? In the controller? On which line?

Comment: Hi @kolas the error is in the view:- `app/views/home/_resultfilters.html.erb where line #16 raised:  <%= f.select :vtype, options_for_select([['Happy Hours Anywhere','Anywhere'],['After Work Drinks','After Work Drinks'],['Somewhere to Relax with Friends', 'Relaxing with Friends'], ['A Club Night','Club Night'], ['Somewhere for Date Night','Date Night'], ['A Place to Watch Sports', 'Watching Sports']]),{} ,:class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight"  %>`

Comment: Hi @Anand, I don't think so? Does that not simply create a new hash?

Comment: I think somehow ```form_for``` uses a ```@results``` which is collection and has not method ```vtype```. For search form its easier to create form with plane html or ```form_tag```. Or you can use gem ```cells```